# Debugging mocha tests run by gulp in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, mocha.js, gulp, intellij-13

I have the following configuration in my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('spec', function() {
  gulp.src('spec/runner.html')
    .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'dot'}))
})
```

When I run nodejs inside IntelliJ Idea, the scripts files imported by spec/runner.html are not loaded by the IDE and therefore the breakpoints are ignored. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

In your run configuration options, for "JavaScript file" put the value:

```
node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
```

Then put your gulp parameters in the "Application parameters".

WebStorm 9 EAP has native [gulp integration](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/webstorm-9-eap-138-1988-meteor-support-gulp-and-more/), but this works until that is final.